# Gnuplot wheel unbind

Tags: gnuplot

I have some medium size graphs which takes 1-2 seconds.
I'm using the `x11` terminal
Sometimes, by accident, I swipe on the plot and this cause the plot to be replotted several times (which hangs my window for several seconds) as shown by `show bind` command:

```
gnuplot> show bind

 <wheel-up>           scroll up (in +Y direction)
 <wheel-down>         scroll down
 <shift-wheel-up>     scroll left (in -X direction)
 <shift-wheel-down>   scroll right
```

would it be possible to unbind these?

I tried with `bind '<wheel-up>' ""` without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable all mouse actions with

```
unset mouse
```

Then enable it, if you want, with

```
set mouse
```

Comment: Ok but then I lose all the mouse stuff. I'll recompile it myself without wheel support and ask to the gnupot devs a "feature enhancement"